# buster.js testing cannot load my js-files

Tags: node.js, buster.js

I've been banging my head at the wall since yesterday (only interrupted by a great Bruce Springsteen concert last night... ;-)

I am trying to add some JS testing to an existing (Rails) project. Basically the folder structure is this:

```
.
├── app
│   └── assets
│       └── javascripts
│           └── strftime.js
└── spec
    ├── buster.js
    └── javascripts
        └── strftime.test.js
```

In this very simple example I've taken the buster example from here https://gist.github.com/cjohansen/1904218 to be sure that everything worked before moving files around.

My **buster.js** looks like this:

```
var config = exports;

config["Server tests"] = {
    // sources: ["../app/assets/javascripts/strftime.js"],
    tests: ["javascripts/strftime.test.js"],

    env: "node"
};
```

and I've tried modifying the first 5 lines of **strftime.test.js** to this:

```
if (typeof require == "function" && typeof module == "object") {
    buster = require("buster");

    require("../app/assets/javascripts/strftime.js");
}
```

Currently when I run buster test, I get this:

```
$ buster test
Failed requiring ./spec/javascripts/strftime.test.js: Cannot find module '../app/assets/javascripts/lib/strftime.js'
```

If I try to uncomment the **sources** line, **buster test** fails silently - even if I try to run it with high debug level.

I've zipped the entire example (2 KB) and put it here, if anyone would like try give it a try: http://gehling.dk/b2.zip

**UPDATE:** I've managed to require the js-file successfully by supplying the path relative to my test-js file:

```
if (typeof require == "function" && typeof module == "object") {
    buster = require("buster");

    require("../../app/assets/javascripts/strftime.js");
}
```

**But I still have the problem with buster failing silently, if I add the sources parameter.**

TIA

/ Carsten

Answer (score 2):

In your zipped `buster.js` you reference a non-existent `lib` dir in your "sources" element:

```
var config = exports;

config["Server tests"] = {
    // sources: ["../app/assets/javascripts/lib/strftime.js"],
    tests: ["javascripts/strftime.test.js"],

    env: "node"
};
```

You also reference the same `lib` directory in `strftime.test.js`.

By changing your `buster.js` to look like this:

```
var config = exports;

config["Server tests"] = {
    rootPath: "../",
    environment: "node",
    sources: ["app/assets/javascripts/strftime.js"],
    tests: ["spec/javascripts/strftime.test.js"],
};
```

And by changing the require statement in `strftime.test.js` to this:

```
require("../../app/assets/javascripts/strftime.js");
```

And running your tests with `buster-test` from within the `spec` dir, you'll get buster attempting to run some tests:

```
$ spec  buster-test
Failure: Date strftime tests %j should return the day of the year
...
```

P.s., don't forget to link buster to your project with `npm link buster`.

**Download the fixed files:** http://speedyshare.com/FGvCe/b2.tar.gz